# How exactly is "ㄱ" pronounced/romanized?

Tags: pronunciation, hangul, translation

As it's said almost everywhere, "ㄱ" is pronounced with a G sound and transliterated as G. However, it's very common to come across situations where ㄱ is romanized as K, specially in names, like Kim, instead of "Gim".

But why? When to use K or G?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Romanization of ㄱ is ambiguous because its aspiration is closer to English 'k', but its voicing is closer to English 'g'. The official Romanization is 'g', but [exceptions are made for certain names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Naming_conventions_(Korean)#Romanization_of_names).

According to [*The Sounds of Korean* by Miho Cho and William O'Grady](https://www.waterstones.com/book/the-sounds-of-korean/miho-choo/miho-choo/9780824859046), pg 39:

> In terms of aspiration, Korean ㄱ falls closer to English unaspirated 'g'
>   than to moderately aspirated 'k'. But in terms of voicing, it is
>   closer to 'k' because both are voiceless. As a result, there is
>   confusion when Korean words are written in English, which is why there
>   is uncertainty over how to spell 김치, which is sometimes written as
>   *kimchi* and sometimes written as *gimchi*. The current official romanization system writes ㄱ as *g* at the beginning of a word.

Comment: Just a note for anybody doing research on this: There seem to be two books called The Sounds of Korean, from different writers: https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=99Ap68FkxawC&oi=fnd&pg=PA77#v=onepage&q&f=false, https://www.waterstones.com/book/the-sounds-of-korean/miho-choo/miho-choo/9780824859046

Answer (score 7):

Word initial it is unvoiced, hence [k]. In medial positions, it becomes voiced, hence [g]. This is a regular phonological process, so native speakers without linguistic training are typically unaware of the difference. Also note that is a regular pattern found in many other Korean consonants.

How you wish to romanize it depends on the romanization scheme. There are [several to choose from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Korean).

Answer (score 1):

Simplistically speaking, it's neither English exactly the same as English 'G' *or* 'K', but (to my ears at least) somewhere in between. The [Revised Romanization of Korean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revised_Romanization_of_Korean#Consonant_letters) suggests G for initial letters, and K for final.

The older [McCune–Reischauer system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McCune%E2%80%93Reischauer#Consonants) Romanised ㄱ as K, and the 'K' has stuck for very common words such as the name 'Kim'.

Comment: Personally, for initial ㄱ, I would use the sound "gh."